# Access primary key/id value during creation of a Django record

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-signals

For my model I use default auto-incremented `PrimaryKey/id` field. I also have a field called `serialNumber` which according to design should reference `id` and generate it's own value based on `id` value.
For example if `id` is `1234` then `serialNumber` field should be a string `'00001234'`.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    serialNumber = models.TextField(max_length=8)
    ...
```

I have no trouble updating `serialNumber` after the creation of record in DB, but my specific case requires `serialNumber` to be set together with object initial creation because right after it I return the record via `REST API`.

I tried using `signals`, but pre_save returns `None`

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(instance.id)
```

On the other hand if I do:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(instance.id)
```

I receive the value for `id` but it's too late because right after `.save()` my `REST API` returns response with created object and I don't want to add code that manages `serialNumber` to serializer.

Overriding `.save()` method for `MyModel` didn't work either:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.id)
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`Id` field still returns `None`.

Anyone has an idea how to access `id` value during initial creation of a record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is no way you can access the ID before saving it.
ID will be generated by database so you have to call `save` method so django sends the data to database and then you'll have your ID

This has been explained in django documentations too:

[Auto-incrementing primary keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys)

If you really need to access the ID which is a unique identifier, you can create one manually.

You can add a field called `my_id` and then give it a unique value before saving the data (you just need to check if that value already exist or not and if it does, then just create another one). This way you'll be able to get a unique ID which you'll be able to find that row with in future.